# runat="server" breaks my jquery / css functionality

Tags: jquery, css, runatserver

I have a page that changes media on a page, like pictures or PDF's, using JQuery so that each user click doesn't require a page refresh / new database access.

I have a DIV container that holds all this activity.  It works and looks great!  When I add runat="server" to the DIV tag, all my nice behaviour breaks.  This is without any code written yet to manipulate the object server side.  For some reason, my styles / behaviours do not get applied correctly.

I'm guessing there is something simple, but I'm tired of guessing.  I'm hoping someone on here knows why that might be happening?

Edit: This is for an ASP.Net application.

```
  <div id="slidingContent" runat="server" >
    <div class="item" id="media3" name="media3">
       My media here.
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: yes, I should have put that in my question.

Comment: okay, see my answer (and others as well)  :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm assuming you have this in the context of a .net application. If so you should specify that somewhere in your question. `runat="server"` will mangle `id`; view the HTML source in your browser to see exactly what it does. You need to add classes to your markup and modify your CSS and JavaScript to use the classes instead of ids.

Comment: yes, I think this is likely the case.  I'm inheriting this project built by a web designer, and I'm adding code behind for loading media pulled from SQL server.  The web of CSS ID's is impressive, and I'm having a tough time navigating it.  I keep breaking the design... argh.

Answer (score 7):

As others have mentioned, if you're using ASP.NET, it's going to modify your ID if you've got runat="server". To workaround, in your JS, use:

```
document.getElementByID("<%=slidingContent.ClientID%>");
```

or

```
$("#<%=slidingContent.ClientID%>");
```

Comment: unfortunately the complexity of the JS I've inherited is too much work to do this.  I have decided to change my approach to minimize impacts to the JS.

Comment: I had to make one change to my JS, and your suggestion here was very valuable.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

do a view source on the rendered page. The id="slidingContent" has probably been changed by asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are using Master / Content pages, but if so, what I've found that works is giving your Master / Content pages an ID.

If you are simply using one of each, and assuming you give the Master page an ID of "Mstr" and the Content page an ID of "Cont", you could create JavaScript prefixes like so:

```
var masterPrefix = "Mstr_",
    contentPrefix = "Cont_";
```

Then, you could create a function called `$getElement()` that would allow you to pass the ID that you give in your markup like so:

```
function $getElement(id) {
    return $("#" + masterPrefix + contentPrefix + id);
}
```

Then, given your specific example, you could get a jQuery object to your runat="server" div by doing the following:

```
var $slidingContent = $getElement("slidingContent");
```

I've found this method to be a life saver when you get into large projects that have heavy client-side scripting.

Alternatively, if you don't like calling another function to return your object, you could always do this:

```
var $slidingContent = $('div[id$="slidingContent"]');
```

Here you are just saying give me the div who has an ID ending in "slidingContent".

Comment: I will play with this idea... thanks.  Really had a hard time understanding the more basic problem that ASP was assigning ID's that was breaking the JS / CSS.  The web designer wrote the site that isn't super friendly when combined with ASP.Net's requirement for assigning ID's to the elements it manipulates.